# Binomial Expansion with Derivatives

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

**Question:**

We have a function $f(t)$ that is defined for all $t \in [0,T]$. From our data, we can estimate two important parameters $\theta \in \mathbb{Z} \backslash 0$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Given $n$, we can also estimate a function $g(n)$. Our estimations are fairly accurate.

Now it appears that there is a pattern. For example, for $\theta > 0$,

we have

\begin{align}
&n=1,\quad g(1)= \frac{d f(t)}{dt}+\theta f(t), \\
&n=2,\quad g(2)= \frac{d^2 f(t)}{dt^2}+\theta^2 f(t)+2\theta \frac{d f(t)}{dt},
\end{align}

and so on; therefore, I think we can write it as an ordinary differential equation $g(n)=(d_t+θ)^n f(t)$
where $d_t$ is a time-derivative operator. Now is there a way to explicitly determine $f(t)$?

**My Attempt 1)**

I tried to use Kovacic algorithm but it seems very complicated and I couldn't get anywhere with it.

**My Attempt 2)**

Although we have a nonhomogeneous equation due to $g(n)$, if for every $n$, we differentiate both sides, we have:

\begin{align}
& n=1,\quad f'' + \theta f'= 0, \\
& n=2,\quad f'''+2 \theta f''+ \theta^2 f'=0,
\end{align}

and so on. If we look closely, the characteristics equation for every $n$
emits two roots, $0$ and $-\theta$ so let us define $C_{1n}$ and $C_{2n}$ two constants and $f_n(t)$, given the value of $n$, then we can write

$$f_n(t) = C_{1n} + C_{2n}e^{- \theta t}.$$

But the problem is that the only condition we have is $f_n(T)=0.$

Any suggestions or comment would be very appreciated. I'm more interested in knowing if there is a solution for $f$ and the method to get there rather than the final solution.

**Edit:**

I think I have made a mistake: since the root $-\theta$ is a repeated root in the second set of ODEs, I think the solution to $f$ is:
$$f_n(t) = C_{0n} + e^{-\theta t}\sum_{k = 1}^{n} C_{kn} t^{k - 1}.$$

Comment: In your attempt, you seem to be assuming that the $g(n)=0.$ I don't see that stated in the problem statement anywhere. Is that the equation you're trying to solve?

Comment: Since $g(n)$ is just a number, $\frac{d g(n)}{d t} =0$. So if we differentiate both sides of the every equation in the first set of equations, we end up with the second sets of equations. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think the answer is $$f(t)=e^{-\theta t}\sum_{i=0}^n a_it^i,$$ but I'm having a hard time proving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you are setting $g(n)=0,$ I think the solution can be found by an intuitive application of variation of parameters:
$$f(t)=e^{-\theta t}\sum_{i=0}^n a_it^i.$$
To get this, I reasoned that $C e^{-\theta t}$ is a solution of $(d_t+\theta)f(t).$ If I raise the power of the operator, I merely raise the order of the root. In the variation of parameters as applied to simple exponential solutions, you just get a higher and higher order polynomial multiplying the exponential. Now we prove that this solution solves the ODE:
\begin{align*}
(d_t+\theta)^nf(t)
&=(d_t+\theta)^n\!\left[e^{-\theta t}\sum_{i=0}^n a_it^i\right]\\
&=\sum_{i=0}^na_i\,(d_t+\theta)^n\left[e^{-\theta t}\,t^i\right].
\end{align*}
Now all we need do is prove that if $n\ge i,$ then
$$(d_t+\theta)^n\left[e^{-\theta t}\,t^i\right]=0.$$
Let us induct on $i,$ here. Suppose $i=0,$ and $n\ge i.$ Then we have
\begin{align*}
(d_t+\theta)^n\left[e^{-\theta t}\right]
&=(d_t+\theta)^{n-1}(d_t+\theta)\left[e^{-\theta t}\right]\\
&=(d_t+\theta)^{n-1}(d_t\left[e^{-\theta t}\right]+\theta\left[e^{-\theta t}\right])\\
&=(d_t+\theta)^{n-1}(0)\\
&=0.
\end{align*}
Now suppose the claim is true for arbitrary $i$ and $n\ge i.$ We show it is true for $i+1,$ assuming $n\ge i+1$ as well. We have
\begin{align*}
(d_t+\theta)^n\left[e^{-\theta t}\,t^{i+1}\right]
&=(d_t+\theta)^{n-1}(d_t+\theta)\left[e^{-\theta t}\,t^{i+1}\right]\\
&=(d_t+\theta)^{n-1}(d_t\left[e^{-\theta t}\,t^{i+1}\right]+\theta\left[e^{-\theta t}\,t^{i+1}\right])\\
&=(d_t+\theta)^{n-1}(-\theta e^{-\theta t}\,t^{i+1}+(i+1)e^{-\theta t}\,t^i+\theta\left[e^{-\theta t}\,t^{i+1}\right])\\
&=(i+1)(d_t+\theta)^{n-1}(e^{-\theta t}\,t^i).
\end{align*}
Since $n\ge i+1,$ we must also have $n-1\ge i,$ forcing $n\ge i,$ and this expression must also be zero. QED.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm slightly confused. Could you please explain why we set $g(n) = 0$? Could you also please help me understand how we can determine $a_i$ coefficients in the second equation?

Comment: It wasn't made clear in the original version of the question exactly what you were trying to do. To fix this is easy: just add a constant to $f(t)$ thus: 
$$f(t)=C+e^{-\theta t}\sum_{i=0}^n a_it^i.$$
As for the $a_i$ coefficients, we don't even try to find out what they are. We need them in the expression to maintain suitable generality. You would only be able to find them if you had initial conditions.